# Horizontal Scrolling in Firefox on Touch (magic mouse/macbook) with no Scroll bar

Tags: firefox, scroll, trackpad

This only happens in firefox with a touch gesture device like the magic mouse or a macbook/macbook pro, but on some websites (some I've done and some I haven't) you can scroll horizontally even though there is no horizontal scrollbar, and there shouldn't be a scroll bar, so it's scrolling to stuff not supposed to be on the page.

http://starryeyedmusic.com/events - scroll to the right (that sidebar is positioned off the viewable page so as to not be seen)

I've also had this happen on some other websites, they work fine with normal mice or on chrome or opera with a trackpad or magic mouse.

-Danny

Answer (score 0):

I did that using middle click and drag to see the example.  On my laptop, I just use my horizontal scroll bar.

I expect that this is happening because the page is rendering larger than the space available.  However, the CSS involved is specifically disallowing scroll bars, though scrolling still works.

I'm not precisely sure if I call that a bug or a feature.. I've found it nice to be able to scroll sideways on random things that are too large (overfilled iframes without scrollbars, for example).

Also, what is your 'question'?

Comment: My question is how to get the horizontal scrolling to stop.

Comment: Stop other people from scrolling like that on your stuff, or stop you from scrolling like that on other people's stuff?

I assume you want to turn it off for yourself, in which case 'disable horizontal scrolling' or a similar option seems like an appropriate answer.